# Equivalence of Text Service Framework for Windows Universal app

Tags: uwp

It was advertised that [Text Service Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms629032(v=vs.85).aspx) API can be used to tap into the input method handling of Windows so that applications can make use of the variety of ways to obtain user input such as voice or gesture typing. I want to access the same thing on Universal app; especially on phones. Is there a way to achieve this?

As a remark, it is unfortunate that all the sample codes linked in the Text Service Framework page are no longer accessible. I can guess that we need to implement the interface [ITextStoreACP2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj670566(v=vs.85).aspx) to interact with the service but there are still a lot of unknown specifics. I would appreciate if someone can show me the new location for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Text Service Framework API is available for Universal App though there is no indication that it will be supported on Windows 10 Mobile.

After searching GitHub for TSF-related interfaces, I came across [this repository](https://github.com/SatishSara/zxlooong/tree/master/Microsoft%20Platform%20SDK%20for%20Windows%20Server%202003%20R2) which includes the old Windows SDK (for Windows Server 2003; which is around the time TSF is introduced i.e. Windows XP). The samples are in `WinUI/tsfapp`, `WinUI/tsfcompart`, ... Copying the essential implementation to Universal app works well on desktop.

On a side note, given that Microsoft purposely removed all official samples, this API will **probably be deprecated** by Microsoft anytime soon.

Comment: The equivalent for UWP is the [Windows.UI.Text.Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.core.aspx) WinRT API.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Do you know a place where I can find some sample? I cannot seem to find one from Microsoft's universal samples github repository.